# Independent rows of select inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out a way of doing something but it is quite hard to explain.  I essentially have 4 dynamic select inputs.  Whenever an option is
selected, an ajax call is fired.  This is how it works.  I have the following dataset

```
array:4 [
  "data" => array:2 [
    2015 => array:2 [
      "english" => array:1 [
        "chips" => array:1 [
          0 => "img1.png"
        ]
      ]
      "french" => array:1 [
        "mussles" => array:1 [
          0 => "img1.png"
        ]
      ]
    ]
    2016 => array:2 [
      "indian" => array:1 [
        "madras" => array:1 [
          0 => "img1.png"
        ]
      ]
      "italien" => array:1 [
        "pasta" => array:1 [
          0 => "img1.png"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

To appropriately display the correct data I do the following

```
<select id="year" class="form-control">
    @foreach($fileData["data"] as $year => $countries)
        <option value="{{ $year }}">{{ $year }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<select id="country" class="form-control hide">
    @foreach($fileData["data"] as $year => $countries)
        @foreach ($countries as $country => $dishes)
            <option class="year-{{ $year }} hide" value="{{ $country }}">{{ $country }}</option>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</select>

<select id="dish" class="form-control hide">
    @foreach($fileData["data"] as $year => $countries)
        @foreach ($countries as $country => $dishes)
            @foreach ($dishes as $dish => $images)
                <option class="year-{{ $year }} country-{{ $country }} hide" value="{{ $dish }}">{{ $dish }}</option>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</select>
```

So the second and third select are hidden until the previous one is chosen.
Within JavaScript I do

```
var getSelectedYear = function() {
    return $("#year option:selected").val();
}

var getSelectedCountry = function() {
    return $("#country option:selected").val();
}

$('#year').change(function() {
    $("#country option.year-" + getSelectedYear()).removeClass('hide');
    $("#country").removeClass('hide');
});

$('#country').change(function() {
    $("#dish option.year-" + getSelectedYear() + ".country-" + getSelectedCountry()).removeClass('hide');
    $("#dish").removeClass('hide');
});

$('#dish').change(function() {
    triggerImageChange();
});
```

So if I choose 2015 in the first select, the second select will display English and french. If I then choose English, the third select will show chips.  I eventually show an image based on the selects, and this is done via an Ajax call.

So this works fine.  Now on the left hand menu I have a comparison link.  When this is clicked, I need to disable the previous selection which is straight forward

```
$('#comparison').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('#year, #country, #dish').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

The problem is this.  I now need to show a new row of selects so the comparison can be made.  Ideally, I do not want to repeat all this code, that would be too much code.

However, I need this row of selects to act independent to the original row.

Would this be possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should wrap the selects with a container div element.

On this element you need to place an id, so you should remove the ids from the select, and use something different to distinguish, like a specific style or a dataset element or just the name attribute will be fine.

On jQuery you point to your div container to find all your elements.

In this way, you could create all the *box* you need with the 3 select and the only difference will be the container id.